# Exiting after run with Requests_Threads and AsyncIO

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio

I am trying out the Requests_Threads library and I've got it where it is returning data to me the way I want it to, but its giving me a `Process finished with exit code 0` and exiting out before going forward.  Anybody used this library and figured it out?

```
from requests_threads import AsyncSession 
import asyncio

class apis:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session=AsyncSession()
        self.main_out=self.session.run(self.main)
        print('still alive')

    async def main(self):
        rs = []
        for _ in range(100):
            rs.append(await self.sub('thing'))

        return[ (x[0].json(),x[1]) for x in rs]

    async def sub(self,key):
        return  await self.session.get('http://httpbin.org/get'),key
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up with a solution using aiohttp

1000 gets using standard Requests took 2 minutes and 4 seconds, using aiohttp it took 56 seconds, or a reduction of a little over 54%.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

class apis:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session=aiohttp.ClientSession()
        self.loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.main_out=self.loop.run_until_complete(self.main())

    async def main(self):
        rs = []
        for _ in range(1000):
            rs.append(await self.loop.create_task(self.sub('foo')))
        return rs

    async def sub(self,key):
        return  await self.session.get('http://httpbin.org/get'),key,datetime.now()
```